# Parsing text file by many delimiters

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to parse text file by many delimiters, but function awk does not work properly in my code. Where I made a mistake ?

I have already tried to read file line by line and I have used awk function to parse my text file
which look like that:

```
===== aaaa ==== zxczxczxc  ==== bbbb  zzzz   .c     
===== aaaa ==== asdasdas   ==== bbbb  mmmm   .c    
===== aaaa ==== aqweqwea   ==== bbbb  zasd   .c
```

As output I would like to get in one variable:

```
zxczxczxc    
asdasdas    
aqweqwea
```

and on second one:

```
zzzz   
mmmm  
zasd
```

```
 #!/bin/bash

input="/path/to/txt/file"
while IFS= read -r var
do
variable1= awk -f "===== aaaa ====,==== bbbb" '{print $2}' $var
variable2= awk -f "==== bbbb,.c" '{print $4}' $var 

done < "$input"
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Running awk inside a loop that is going line by line seems like an odd choice. Can you share more sample lines from the file and also what you are trying to get as output. I have a strong suspicion this could be done in one small awk command.

Comment: I have added already more lines @JNevill

Comment: Something like `sed -r 's/===== aaaa ==== (.*)  ==== bbbb  (.*) .c/\1\2/ `?

Comment: @Walter A Thanks for answer, but this sed returns all text

Comment: Try things with `sed` with your data. Perhaps you have tabs, not spaces or something else.

Comment: Do you want `variable1` to be filled with all fields concatetenated as different lines, or are you going to use the variable inside your loop before it is overwritten by the next line?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you want then edit your question to be much clearer:

```
$ foo=$(awk '{print $4}' file)
$ bar=$(awk '{print $7}' file)
$ echo "$foo"
zxczxczxc
asdasdas
aqweqwea
$ echo "$bar"
zzzz
mmmm
zasd
```